# My code does not add a percentage to the data base like it's meant to

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to add percentage to my database, but it doesn't work.

This is my attempt at doing this:

```
Use SKILLAGEITDB
go

Create procedure [spAddPercentage] 
as
    declare @incPercent decimal(2,0) 
begin
    update OrderDetails
    set Value = Value  * 0.1

     if @incpercent < 0.1 
        update OrderDetails
        set Value = Value * 0.1 

     if @incpercent > 0.1 
        update orderdetails 
        set value = value * 0.1
     else
        if @incpercent = 0.1 
            print 'finished'
end
```

Comment: Please give us the input and expected output.

Comment: the idea of the code is to add 10 percent to the value column on the orderdetails table.

Comment: "But it doesn't work" is wildly unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, so many things...

1. why have three different cases when they all do the same thing?
2. The syntax is inconsistent.. If you don't use an `else` for the second case, why are you using `else` in the last case ?
3. Since you multiply the Value by 0.1 in the first line, regardless of what `@incpercent` is, the rest of the code is redundant.

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: it's supposed to plus 10 percent to the total value on the value column on the orderdetails table.

Comment: ... Regardless of what `@incpercent` is?  What's that part for?

Answer (score 0):

> the idea of the code is to add 10 percent to the value column on the orderdetails table.

To do that it would be Value * 1.1 (e.g. set Value = Value * 1.1 or set Value *= 1.1)